# Uncaught TypeError: CKEDITOR.style.customHandlers[e.type] is not a constructor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor_rails (4.5.10).  ITs working fine on local (development ) but when i deploy using capistrano, getting error like this

> Uncaught TypeError: CKEDITOR.style.customHandlers[e.type] is not a constructor

Any idea?

Comment: Please let us know what you already tried to solve the issue.

Comment: I just follow https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails

Comment: Add ckeditor into `precompile`. Please refer this https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails#asset-compilation-process-does-not-produce-js-andor-css-files